# npm development web server restart

Tags: node.js, macos, reactjs, npm

i'm learning react using a video course. in the videos, the instructor does an `npm start` and every change he makes to the codebase after that is reflected immediately on the `localhost:3000`. However, each time I make a change, I have to kill the webserver and then restart it to see the changes. Why is this happening? I have the latest version of stable node and both the instructor and myself are on OSX. I've since googled about the problem and several npm packages are available to address this issue, however, is it possible that on the instructor's this happens out of the box? please help i'd like to continue to learn react.

Comment: He's possibly using nodemon, or if he's using webpack-dev server to host, that's what's doing ti.

Comment: he specifically does 'npm start', makes us install the same packages as he is using via a file, i don't see him doing anything different in a step-by-step tutorial

Comment: could you please open package.json file and then find the row with `scripts: { start: "" }` and past it in your question it will be very helpfull

Comment: `"start": "react-scripts start"`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see the change, you will have to restart node.js server.

If you want to restart server automatically, I recommand nodemon library!!

https://github.com/remy/nodemon

You can restart the server without having to do anything!